# PNG32 vs PNG24 vs PNG8

Tags: adobe-photoshop, png, adobe-fireworks

I thought there is only PNG8 and png32, but photoshop has option for PNG24, and fireworks has all 3 options. Which is better for web world?

Also when I export PNG24 with alpha transparency in fireworks, it always adds background color, but in photoshop, it exports with alpha .

Answer (score 9):

"Also when I export PNG24 with alpha transparency in fireworks, it always adds background color, but in photoshop, it exports with alpha ."

You need a PNG32 for the alpha channel, so when you save a PNG24 with an alpha channel, PhotoShop actually makes it a PNG32.

In Fireworks, it actually let's you manually make the decision, so if you choose PNG24, you lose the alpha channel in the process.

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know 8 bit equals 256 colors, you can choose to have a color transparent (gif) which leaves you with 255+1 solid alpha.  Rgb = 24 (3 × 8) 256 for red, 256 for green, 256 for blue (about 16,7 mil. Combinations) , adding another 8 bits for a 256 degree alpha chanel, so 4x8 = 32bits for rgba