# is PNG-24 being converted to PNG-32 in Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, png, transparency

when i save an image in Photoshop as a PNG-24 with trans on, does PS actually convert that to PNG-32 but not tell me about it?

Comment: Some good clarifications about this issue:
**DeepBlueSky Blog:**
[The difference between PNG24 and PNG32](http://www.deepbluesky.com/blog/-/the-difference-between-png24-and-png32_49)
**Graphic Design SE:** [PNG32 vs PNG24 vs PNG8](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/6151/png32-vs-png24-vs-png8)

Answer (score 5):

Yes. Transparency is the other 8 bits. PNG32 = 8 Red, 8Green, 8 Blue, 8 alpha